# Stop WordPress from filtering out draft posts for guests in get_posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a `page` on my WordPress site which uses a template and in that template, I have used `get_posts` to fetch results for my CPT. In my CPT, only one post is allowed to have `publish` status at a time whilst others stay in `draft` mode. However, I want guest users (i.e. site visitors who don't have access to an account on my site) be able to visit that page and see those posts in their draft state.

I'm using these args to fetch results

```
$args = array(
              'name' => $slug,
              'post_type' => 'catalog',
              'post_status' => array('draft', 'publish'),
              );
$catalogs = get_posts($args);
```

The code above works fine for signed in users but it returns empty when I sign out. I'm sure that some WordPress filter is responsible for this. I can't figure out how to make it stop.

Additional info: I can use `$wpdb` to fetch desired results but I'm hoping that this can also be done by some custom filter. I did my research but couldn't find anything useful and WordPress Codex doesn't contain any information regarding this.

Comment: the code you have placed in doesn't add up to what is happening. It's definitely not the code you've placed there that is causing it. What is causing it may be a code in your website which we will never know as there is no filter or hook that can cause your snippets to not run when user is not logged in. my suggestion is, disable all plugins or action hook in your theme to determine what is happening.

Comment: I have checked the code too but there's nothing there that could be doing this. All the plugins used are written by me and none of them really hooks into how posts are retrieved. I did find some people on the internet saying that WordPress does disable draft posts from being accessed by guests

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i think i get what you mean. Try the below snippets

```
/*
 * On drafts should be visible.
 */
function show_drafts( $query ) {
    $query->set( 'post_status', array( 'publish', 'draft' ) );
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'show_drafts' );
```

this should allow both draft and publish to appear visible to everyone when you use get_posts method.

Comment: Still not getting any drafts. I've also tried using `$args['post_status'] = array('any');` but that didn't help either.